# Combining mypy Union and nested TypedDict causes mypy errror: incompatible return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, union, mypy

I would like to combine `TypedDict` with with `Union`. So that a function is able to return either `A` or `B`. Mypy is able to correctly detect a `TypedDict` return type directly. But when a `TypedDict` is nested in an `Union` it doesn't work.

```
from typing_extensions import TypedDict
from typing import Union


class A(TypedDict):
    a: str


class B(TypedDict):
    b: str


def works() -> A:
    return {'a': 'value'}
    # Works as expected


def problem() -> Union[A, B]:
    return {'a': 'value'}
    # mypy_error: Incompatible return value type (got "Dict[str, str]", expected "Union[A, B]")
    # Reports an error while it should be valid


def workaround() -> Union[A, B]:
    x: A = {'a': 'value'}

    return x
    # This works again but is not very elegant
```

A possible workaround would be to assign to temporary returned type hinted variable (see `workaround()`). Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Note: Python 3.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quote from [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/):

> An explicit [TypedDict] type annotation is generally needed, as otherwise an ordinary dictionary type could be assumed by a type checker, for backwards compatibility. When a type checker can infer that a constructed dictionary object should be a TypedDict, an explicit annotation can be omitted.

So there's nothing wrong with defining the type explicitly in your code. Another possibility is to "instantiate" `A` directly:

```
def problem() -> Union[A, B]:
    return A(a='value')
```

Although this is of course only a syntactic sugar and will be replaced with `dict` at runtime.